# printing title of URL from a file in python

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to fetch URL from file and output the title of page :

```
import lxml.html
file = open('ab.txt','r')
for line in file:
    t = lxml.html.parse(line)
    print t.find(".//title").text
```

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\site.py", line 4, in <module>
    t = lxml.html.parse(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 661, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2706, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:49958)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1500, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71797)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1529, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72080)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1429, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:71175)
  File "parser.pxi", line 975, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68173)
  File "parser.pxi", line 539, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64257)
  File "parser.pxi", line 625, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:65178)
  File "parser.pxi", line 563, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64493)
IOError: Error reading file 'http://example.com/5129860
': failed to load HTTP resource
```

The ab.txt has:

```
   example.com/123

    example.com/234

    example.com/456
    ....
```

Anything wrong in here?

Comment: What is your expected output? do you want to download the contents of each of the url and print the title?

Answer (score 1):

The `parse` method in `lxml.html` parses a filename, URL, or file-like object into an HTML document and returns a tree. From the documentation, the arguments of this function  are like this,

```
parse(filename_or_url, parser=None, base_url=None, **kw)
```

So you can directly pass the filename and get your output.

```
t = lxml.html.parse('ab.txt')
print t.find(".//title").text
```

Comment: print t.find(".//title")  returns None

Comment: example.com/123 
example.com/234 
example.com/456 
    
This is the format

Comment: This file will give you `None`. There is no `title` in this file. why are you using lxml? what is your expected output by the way?

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file:
    t = lxml.html.parse(line)
    print t.find(".//title").text
```

Here you are trying to read each line and parse each line using the `lxml.html.parse` Which means that the argument to function is not a valid http content. you should be modifiying these lines as

```
 from urllib2 import urlopen

 for line in file:
    content = urlopen(line)
    t = lxml.html.parse(content)
    print t.find(".//title").text
```

Here the entire content of the file, is read to variable `content`. There by it contains a valid http content.

Comment: still, failed to load http resource .

Comment: see the edit it should work. the file name is to be mentioned.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I have already answered the part which you have edited.